# How to write a SQL query to search all the columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select *
from DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS
where (
    ORDER_ITEM_ID like '%1%' || 
    ORDER_ID like '%1%' ||
    PRODUCT_ID like '%1%' ||
    UNIT_PRICE like '%1%'
);
```

Is this the correct query to search and fetch the searched record from database from all the columns?

Comment: Is this for your homework?

Comment: Did you run the code and see? If you did, was somethind wrong with the result?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need an `OR`:

```
select *
    from DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS
    where (
           ORDER_ITEM_ID like '%1%' OR
           ORDER_ID      like '%1%' OR
           PRODUCT_ID    like '%1%' OR
           UNIT_PRICE    like '%1%'
          );
```

Please notice that the parentheses are not necessary here; however, as  Matthew McPeak noticed, they give no issue and can be useful in case you need to add some other condition in `AND` to the existing `OR` conditions.

The `||` is the operator for [concatenation in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-language-fundamentals.htm#GUID-4792284C-D82B-4F6A-8554-45CF1BFAE6EB); for example:

```
SQL> select 'a' || 'b' from dual;

'A
--
ab
```

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary, but possibly a good idea because they'll help someone avoid incorrect query results if they later have to add an `AND` condition.

Comment: The `||` is not only the concatenation operator for Oracle. It's the one defined in the SQL standard.